# How to align captions inside different subfloats inside minipages?

Tags: subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I have multiple subfloats inside minipages as shown below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{xparse}


\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\lstset{
language=c++, 
keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\scriptsize, 
numberblanklines=false,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
stringstyle=\ttfamily,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=2,
xleftmargin=1em,
showstringspaces=false,
}

\newsavebox{\boxedminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxedminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\boxedminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\boxedminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
   \begin{minipage}{0.565\textwidth}
    {
    \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
      \subfloat[Small Code Caption]{
      %\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{small_code.txt}
        %\end{minipage}
      }
      \end{boxedminipage}

      \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
      \subfloat[Large Code Caption]{
       %\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{large_code.txt}
        %\end{minipage}
      }
       \end{boxedminipage}
    }
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.41\textwidth}
    {
    \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
      \subfloat[Moderate Code Caption]{
        \lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{moderate_code.txt}
      }
       \end{boxedminipage}

    \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
      \subfloat[Another Small Code Caption]{
        \lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{small_code.txt}
      }
       \end{boxedminipage}
  }
    \end{minipage}
    %
  \caption{Weird Code Figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:
[image]

I want to center-align captions (a) and (b), and captions (c) and (d). I tried doing so by adding minipages inside subfloats (see the commented lines), but that messed up the spacing even more because the code inside (b) and (c) went into multiple lines.

Note that adding `\centering` before `\ignorespaces` ends up moving all the codes as well which I do not want:
[image]

How can I align only the captions properly such that the code statements start on the left?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is simply adding `\centering` before `\ignorespaces` inside the definition of your "`\boxedminipage`" what you want?

Comment: Can you pls provide an example, that we can just copy and instantly compile? i.e. something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

Comment: @Max Full code added.

Comment: @Nico Adding `\centering` moves the code snippets as well, and then the code is not aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the subfloat as wide as the box which you need to center the caption in.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_small.txt}
system.out.println("Short text");
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_moderate.txt}
system.out.println("Some moderately long text");
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_large.txt}
system.out.println("Some very very very very very very long text");
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.9cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{xparse}


\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\lstset{
  language=c++, 
  keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
  numbers=left, 
  numberstyle=\scriptsize, 
  numberblanklines=false,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  stringstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=1em,
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\newsavebox{\boxedminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxedminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\boxedminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\boxedminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par%\kern#2
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\begin{minipage}{0.565\textwidth}
  \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
  \subfloat[Small Code Caption]{%
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{\jobname_small.txt}}%
  }
  \end{boxedminipage}

  \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
  \subfloat[Large Code Caption]{%
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{\jobname_large.txt}}%
  }
  \end{boxedminipage}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.41\textwidth}
  \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
  \subfloat[Moderate Code Caption]{%
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{\jobname_moderate.txt}}%
  }
  \end{boxedminipage}

  \begin{boxedminipage}{\textwidth}
  \subfloat[Another Small Code Caption]{%
    \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\lstinputlisting[numbers=none]{\jobname_small.txt}}%
  }
  \end{boxedminipage}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Weird Code Figure}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Be careful with end-of-lines that can produce spaces.

[image]

Comment: Works! Thanks! I was trying to do that using another minipage or tabularx, but that didn't work.

Comment: If you are going to specify the width, why not use a subfigure (subcaption package)?  It also now supplies its own \subfloat (for backward compatibility).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Maybe the OP uses a document class that's not compatible with `caption`.